# Using ARIMA time series with daily data for one year

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I have a 13month dataset with daily observations of reported bike theft in >100 regions of a city. I'd like to use that dataset to make predictions of number of bike theft by region. A lots contain zeros, since not in every region there is a reported bike theft every day. Also, I assume I won't be able to detect any seasonal component because every season only appears once in the dataset (though across different regions). Can I still do daily and monthly predictions per region using that dataset?

Comment: Seasonal component not only about months: for example, you can find that most of the bikes was theft on Thursday. So try different granularities to find seasonal component. Try [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-complete-guide-to-time-series-data-visualization-in-python-da0ddd2cfb01) to see the dependencies in your data.
After this you probably find out which models you can try for predictions.